# how to detect a proxy using javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy

in a web page, is there a way to detect by javascript if a web browser is using a PAC file http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/toto.pac ?
Notes : the same page can be viewd behind many PACs, i don't want to use a server end language, i can edit the toto PAC file if necessary. Regards

Answer (score 10):

You could make an ajax request to a known external server (google.com) and then get the headers out of that request to see if the proxy headers are in the request...

```
var proxyHeader = 'via';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send();
var header = req.getResponseHeader(proxyHeader);
if (header) {
    // we are on a proxy
}
```

Change `proxyHeader` to what ever your proxy adds to the response.

EDIT: You will have to add a conditional for supporting the IE implementation of `XMLHttpRequest`

EDIT:

I am on a proxy at work and I have just tested this code in jsfiddle and it works. Could be made prettier so that is supports IE and does an async get but the general functionality is there... http://jsfiddle.net/unvHW/

It turns out that detecting 'via' is much better...

Comment: Indeed, this looks familiar ;)

Comment: Ok thank you, but it seems like via parameter takes differents values cross browsers whereas proxy-authenticate is missing...

Comment: @dinine Sorry mate I do not (that might be one for a networking board), but you will see in my edit above that I have tried this from work and it does work using 'via' as the header.

Answer (score 2):

**Note that this solution will not work on every proxy and would *probably* only work if you are BEHIND the proxy :**

Some proxies append a field in the response headers of an HTTP request which is called : `X-Forwarded-For`

Maybe you can achieve what you are trying to do with an AJAX request to `google.com` for example and check if the field is there.

Something like this :

```
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:'http://www.google.com',
   data: formData,
   success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        if(request.getResponseHeader('X-Forwarded-For')) !== undefined)
            alert("Proxy detected !");
   }
  });
```

Edit: As Michael said, the X-Forwarded-For is only appended to requests. You'd better check for the response header your proxy puts in the response header.

Comment: I am not 100% but I think 'X-Forwarded-For' is only appended to requests.. but kudos for having the same answer as me haha

Comment: Sorry i have'nt mentioned that i'm always behind a proxy so with your solution i'll only detect if a proxy is used but not toto one

Comment: Replace if(request.getResponseHeader('someResponseField')) !== undefined) by if(request.getResponseHeader('someResponseField')) == "Your proxy's response field value")

Comment: Pretty sure you won't be able to AJAX www.google.com unless your code is hosted there. You'll have to AJAX something on the domain you're on.

Answer (score -2):

No.

Browsers do not expose that sort of configuration data to websites.